# phpunit fails after a number of tests

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I run phpunit from the command line for a laravel website.

The output (first line) is:

```
.................FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.FFFFFFFFF.FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.  63 / 105 ( 60%)
```

However, all those tests run fine individually. It's when I run them all together that most of them fail.

All errors show code 500, 200 expected.

example:

```
<pre>
not ok 99 - Failure: TeamTest::testApiShow
---
message: 'A GET request to ''http://localhost/api/v1/teams/1'' failed. Got a 500 code instead.'
severity: fail
</pre>
```

Details

> Error occurs in line 47 of
>   [..]vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php
>
> ```
> line 47: return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
> ```

full output: http://pastebin.com/bt29w7Lz
config of phpunit: http://pastebin.com/pBT59aXM

Comment: Have you tried running `phpunit --verbose` to get more useful output?

Comment: most show ```PDOException on [..]vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php line 47```

Comment: Is that all? Try posting your full output to a pastebin.com and share the link

Comment: see http://pastebin.com/bt29w7Lz

Comment: Can you do the same with phpunit.xml ? You can hide your password first.

Comment: see http://pastebin.com/pBT59aXM

Comment: Try adding DB configuration to phpunit.xml: `<env name="DB_HOST" value="localhost"/>`. You will also need to set: `DB_DATABASE`, `DB_USERNAME`, `DB_PASSWORD`, of yout **testing database.**

Answer (score 1):

It may be the case that there are too many database connections open.  Both PostgreSQL and MySQL have a limit on the number of connections available, and phpUnit neither pools connections nor does it return connections to the pool once they are used.

I frequently have to increase the maximum connections for PostgreSQL on my Jenkins (unit test) servers to 500 or more to run the full unit test suite.

See more here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections

Comment: I am running on shared hosting, and I can't change the maximum number of connections. Is there a way to slow down phpunit, so I have less connections open?

Comment: Sorry, slowing down phpUnit isn't going to help, the issue is that the connections don't get discarded until the phpUnit process exits.  Can you just try running the testing locally -- e.g. on a virtual machine on your own PC?

Comment: I have a version setup on my local machine and there it's working. I just want to be able to run it online too, to make sure everything is honky-dory.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of too many SQL connections and luckily there is a way to resolve it: close the MySQL connections during tearDown. On Laravel this looks like:

```
public function tearDown()
{
    $this->beforeApplicationDestroyed(function () {
        foreach (\DB::getConnections() as $connection) {
            $connection->disconnect();
        }
    });

    parent::tearDown();
}
```

based on: https://www.neontsunami.com/posts/too-many-connections-using-phpunit-for-testing-laravel-51